# How to change ballon location in amChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I'm actually building an [amchart](https://www.amcharts.com) but I can't find a way to modify the position of the balloons that appear on my bullets.

Here is my code :

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      ...
      "balloon": {
        "textAlign" : "left",
        "color" : "#000000",
        "fixedPosition" : false,
        "offsetX" : 50,
        "offsetY" : 50,
        "animationDuration" : 0.3,
        "borderAlpha" : 0,
        "borderColor" : "#FFFFFF",
        "cornerRadius" : 0,
        "pointerWidth" : 0,
        "showBullet" : false,
        "horizontalPadding" : 5,
        "verticalPadding" : 5,
      }
    });
```

But here is what I get : 
[image]
Why the offsetX and offsetY don't have any effect on my ballon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmBalloon#offsetX), `offsetX` and `offsetY` only work when `fixedPosition` is set to false and the chart cursor is disabled. Since you have the cursor enabled, it won't work. You'll need to use an external div if you want to change the position while using a cursor, similar to [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/displaying-rollover-information-fixed-position-div/). Note that the `changed` listener will go into the [stock panel](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel#changed) for the stock chart.

Comment: So their is an error is the doc? : NOTE: this setting is ignored unless fixedPosition is set to false or Chart Cursor is enabled.

Comment: It's not exactly clear at first glance. I'll let them know to tweak it.